# How to prevent additional information from being combined into this regex?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Given the following test strings:

```
A simple paper
A simple, burnt paper
```

I want to match against the key "simple" (which can also be other keys) but NOT include certain additional information. For example, a simple paper is the same as a simple, green paper; both are considered simple papers and should have a matching key.

I have the following regex:

`A (?P<key>.+)(?:, green|) paper`

The problem is that I can't seem to split out the ", green" portion to be ignored.

An additional inputs to clarify that whitespace is required for the key group:

```
A fairly complex paper
A fairly complex, green paper
```

Both of these should match where `key` is `fairly complex` only.

An additional inputs to clarify the exclusion group:

```
A simple, torn paper
A simple, torn, green paper
```

Both of these should match where `key` is `simple, torn` because `, green` is specified as optional for the purpose of filtering by explicit exclusion.

What I'm trying to say by `(?:, green|)` is that `, green` MAY appear at this point and if it is, capture it outside of the `key` group so that it does not appear there.

Possible characters for key include:

`[a-zA-Z,_\- ]` -- Notice the inclusion of space `[ ]` and comma `[,]`.

Comment: Maybe you want [`A (?P<key>\S+)(?:, \S+)* paper`](https://regex101.com/r/ml9uLW/1)?

Comment: You've changed the regex for `?P<key>` to exclude whitespace characters with `\S`. This is incompatible with known-possible keys which include characters `[a-zA-Z,_\- ]`.

Comment: Cool, then, [check `A (?P<key>[a-zA-Z_-]+)(?:, [a-zA-Z_-]+)* paper`](https://regex101.com/r/ml9uLW/3).

Comment: You have again excluded whitespace from the key group which is necessary for certain matches. I've added some additional inputs to clarify.

Comment: No, I did not *exclude* anything, I just arranged the chars in such a way that you can match the items properly. If the space between the items is optional, you may use `*` quantifier. You can't solve the problem if you do not invest some effort into defining the pattern you want to match. Right now, it is not possible to solve the problem as you have not provided enough details for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: [`(An?(?: [A-Za-z_-]+)*)(?:,[A-Za-z_ -]+)*( [A-Za-z_-]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ml9uLW/6)

To drop the middle part, instead of taking the whole match, take group 1 and group 2 and join them together i.e. `match[1] + match[2]` in whatever language you are using.

Comment: Added additional clarification to how I'm trying to apply a group for the purpose of excluding trailing strings from the `key` group. Note that the key group may contain a comma which is why I'm specifying exclusions explicitly. As soon as I re-apply a comma to your regex, it fails to match the same inputs as my initial regex: `(An?(?: [A-Za-z,_-]+)*)(?:, green|, pretty)* paper` (regex simplified for clarity).